# Generating a PDF from an angular.js form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I need to make a form that upon submission uses the input to make a PDF. 
I am using angular for the form data and handling so it would make sense if there was a way to leverage angular in the generation of the PDF.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18478810/2051952).

Comment: i've looked into jsPDF im looking for something more angular based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help you!! http://blog.sayan.ee/angular-pdf/

*HTML code-sample*

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="DocCtrl">
  <ng-pdf template-url="viewer.html"></ng-pdf>
</div>
```

*AngularJs code-sample*

```
app.controller('DocCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pdfUrl = '/path/to/all/pdf/' + $routeParams.pdfname + '.pdf';
});
```

Comment: The link provided doesn't work anymore. Try this instead:  [https://blog.sayan.ee/angular-pdf](https://blog.sayan.ee/angular-pdf)